# Cpu fan does not speed up according to heat level

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I have just changed my motherboard, ram and processor. Everything is going fine but fan speed when cpu heats. Fan speeds do not change according to cpu temperature. I have tried to open smart fan control on bios but there is no smart fan control option and also tried to change my cpu fan speed via msi control center. It is shown that cpu fan is at full speed(100%) on msi control center but, it is not. I have seen these fans spin at 2200 RPM before i change cpu and motherboard. CPU fan 1 speed is at 1178RPM full speed, and CPU fan 2 speed is 0 RPM.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What makes you think there is a fan connect to the `CPU Fan 2`?  All evidence point to the fact, you have a single fan, connected to `CPU Fan ` 1` outside of any other case fans that might exist.  Are you really concerned about 22 RPM difference?

Comment: I am concerned about low fan speed high cpu temperature. I did connect CPU fan 1 and 2.

Comment: Solved. @Ramhound The company, from which i bought the motherboard, said it is faulty. Motherboard going to get replaced.

Comment: 1022 rpm difference.....

Answer (score 0):

My all in one computer quit working after uploading windows 10, I took it in to be repaired and the motherboard was burned up from the computer over heating after running for hours on end to load windows 10. The Tech guys said it is a common problem when loading windows 10 as the fans can only cool so much heat being generated. The tech guys said that there was nothing that could be done as far as the fan cooling goes.